# React / Typescript - React.createElement

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an object which contains a reference to a FunctionalComponent however when I pass that reference into the `createElement` statement it is throwing a TS error.

**Question:** why is this complaining? my interface excepts both `Component` and `FunctionalComponent`.

[image: error-message]

**Example:**

```
const someFunctionalComponent: React.FC = () => {
  return <div></div>
}
const anotherFunctionalComponent: React.FC = () => {
  return <div></div>

}

const somePages = [someFunctionalComponent, anotherFunctionalComponent];

interface TabPage {
  active: number;
  content: React.Component | React.FC;
}


somePages.forEach(page => React.createElement(page))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting confused between the component *instance* and the component *class*.  The name of a `class` like `React.Component` represents a the type for an instance of that class.  `React.createElement` is looking for a constructor rather than an instance.

The type for the class constructor is `React.ComponentClass`.  You could use `content: React.ComponentClass | React.FC`.  But there is actually a built-in helper for this union which is `React.ComponentType<Props>`.

```
interface TabPage {
  active: number;
  content: React.ComponentType;
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/9WvMYm)